# I want to add millisecond to current date in snowflake using Interval function

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to add milliseconds to current date but thats not adding

(current_timestamp + INTERVAL  '.001 SECOND')  --> doesnt add value

I wanted is for ex -
2003-03-06 23:59:59.000
then after executing this above statement it should give
2003-03-06 23:59:59.001

but still its showing "2003-03-06 23:59:59.000"

If I try to do this it works
(current_timestamp + INTERVAL  '1 SECOND') --> this adds one second but I am not able to add '0.001 second'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using MILLISECONDS instead of SECONDS?

```
select current_timestamp, current_timestamp + INTERVAL '1 MILLISECONDS';
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-datetime.html#supported-date-and-time-parts-for-intervals

Comment: Great. Thanks for quick help. That worked. I tried 1 millisecond but not 1 milliseconds. Got the desired result

Comment: @Rohan you are welcome. Maybe there was another issue with your test, cause MILLISECOND should also work. Please don't forget to mark the answer correct if your question is answered.

Comment: Ohh yes.  Got the other issue as well. 

select current_timestamp, current_timestamp + INTERVAL '1 MILLISECONDS' , current_timestamp + INTERVAL '1 MILLISECOND';

This also works